# What Happens If A Container Is Created Within A Kubernetes Pod By docker-compose?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-in-docker

I believe this isn't anything to worry about, but I can't find a definitive answer on this. If DinD creates a new container via docker-compose, and the DinD container is **within** a Kubernetes pod, what happens when the pod is destroyed on the node?

My teammates seem to think that the container runtime will properly clean up all containers, even those not created via kubelet, but I can't find anything to 100% support this assumption.